# EC2 userdata script runs very slowly on Centos7 AMI

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, user-data

There appears to be a 25 second delay every time a userdata script touches the disk on the centos 7 AMI from AWS marketplace.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
echo "[TIMER] START $(date +%s.%N)"
current_user=$(whoami)
echo "Running as: $current_user"
sudo id -u myuser &>/dev/null || sudo useradd myuser
echo "[TIMER] CreatedUser $(date +%s.%N)"
time sudo yum update -y
echo "[TIMER] Yum Update $(date +%s.%N)"
sudo mkdir -p /opt/myuser/resources
echo "[TIMER] Create /opt/myuser/resources $(date +%s.%N)"

sudo bash -c "cat > /etc/systemd/system/my-service.service" <<EOF
[Unit]
Description=My Service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=myuser
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/bash -ex -c 'echo "Hello World"'

[Install]
Alias=my-service
WantedBy=default.target
EOF

echo "[TIMER] Make my-service.service $(date +%s.%N)"
sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/my-service.service
echo "[TIMER] Chmod $(date +%s.%N)"
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
echo "[TIMER] daemon-reload $(date +%s.%N)"
sudo systemctl enable my-service
echo "[TIMER] enable $(date +%s.%N)"
sudo systemctl start my-service
echo "[TIMER] END: my-service $(date +%s.%N)"
```

I launch a c5.large of this AMI and use the above as my userdata script: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00O7WM7QW

Timers result:

```
[TIMER] START 1546978269.809559549
[TIMER] CreatedUser 1546978320.472706964
[TIMER] Yum Update 1546978356.991642552
[TIMER] Create /opt/myuser/resources 1546978382.033044767
[TIMER] Make my-service.service 1546978407.074353857
[TIMER] Chmod 1546978432.111791937
[TIMER] daemon-reload 1546978457.195078083
[TIMER] enable 1546978482.265036318
[TIMER] END: my-service 1546978507.313735938
```

```
| CENTOS 7                                                  |                      |             |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|----------------------|-------------|
|                                                           |                      |             |
| log                                                       | timestamp            | seconds     |
| [TIMER] START 1546978269.809559549                        | 1546978269.809559549 |             |
| [TIMER] CreatedUser 1546978320.472706964                  | 1546978320.472706964 | 50.66315007 |
| [TIMER] Yum Update 1546978356.991642552                   | 1546978356.991642552 | 36.51893997 |
| [TIMER] Create /opt/myuser/resources 1546978382.033044767 | 1546978382.033044767 | 25.04139996 |
| [TIMER] Make my-service.service 1546978407.074353857      | 1546978407.074353857 | 25.04131007 |
| [TIMER] Chmod 1546978432.111791937                        | 1546978432.111791937 | 25.03743982 |
| [TIMER] daemon-reload 1546978457.195078083                | 1546978457.195078083 | 25.08328009 |
| [TIMER] enable 1546978482.265036318                       | 1546978482.265036318 | 25.06995988 |
| [TIMER] END: my-service 1546978507.313735938              | 1546978507.313735938 | 25.04870009 |
|                                                           |                      |             |
|                                                           | total (s)            | 237.50418   |
|                                                           |                      |             |
|                                                           | total (m)            | 3.958402999 |
```

If you scroll to the right in my ASCII table you can see that simple commands like `mkdir`, `chmod`, and `useradd` are taking 25 seconds. Why does this happen?

EDIT:

contents of `/etc/hosts`

```
$ hostname
ip-172-31-40-213.us-west-2.compute.internal
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

example log from `/var/log/messages`, the systemd logs show that creating the sudo session takes the 25 seconds:

```
Jan  9 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166 cloud-init: + echo '[TIMER] Make my-service.service 1547077832.899069408'
Jan  9 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166 cloud-init: [TIMER] Make my-service.service 1547077832.899069408
Jan  9 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166 cloud-init: + sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/my-service.service
Jan  9 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Jan  9 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166 systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Jan  9 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166 systemd: Started Session c3 of user root.
Jan  9 23:50:57 ip-172-31-35-166 cloud-init: ++ date +%s.%N
Jan  9 23:50:57 ip-172-31-35-166 cloud-init: + echo '[TIMER] Chmod 1547077857.946078493'
Jan  9 23:50:57 ip-172-31-35-166 cloud-init: [TIMER] Chmod 1547077857.946078493
```

`journalctl` log shows the likely culprit:

```
Jan 09 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal cloud-init[1197]: + echo '[TIMER] Make my-service.service 1547077832.899069408'
Jan 09 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal cloud-init[1197]: [TIMER] Make my-service.service 1547077832.899069408
Jan 09 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal cloud-init[1197]: + sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/my-service.service
Jan 09 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Jan 09 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal sudo[13392]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/my-service.service
Jan 09 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of root.
Jan 09 23:50:32 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started Session c3 of user root.
Jan 09 23:50:57 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal sudo[13392]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Failed to create session: Connection timed out
Jan 09 23:50:57 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal sudo[13392]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 09 23:50:57 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal sudo[13392]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 09 23:50:57 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal cloud-init[1197]: ++ date +%s.%N
Jan 09 23:50:57 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal cloud-init[1197]: + echo '[TIMER] Chmod 1547077857.946078493'
Jan 09 23:50:57 ip-172-31-35-166.us-west-2.compute.internal cloud-init[1197]: [TIMER] Chmod 1547077857.946078493
```

Googling more, I find: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2863

This has been fixed in a later version of systemd but centos on AWS EC2 comes with systemd version 219 and I can't really update it myself. Any suggestions? Is there some config I can place to avoid this issue? I can remove *most* instances of sudo in my userdata script but I do need it for things like:

```
sudo -H -u myuser bash -ex <<EOF
  ... commands
EOF
```

FWIW Amazon Linux 2 comes with the same version of systemd but does not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: It is because of `sudo`. In your case, it is waiting on something to timeout before executing the command. Can you try the same command with and without `sudo`? Can you post the contents of the machine's `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: @helloV that did indeed fix it. I've added the contents of `/etc/hosts` to my post. Searching around the internet shows that this might be a reverse dns lookup timeout, is that right? Can you explain the root cause a little more in depth?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand the solution. This is not how StackOverflow in meant to be used. You have clearly benefited from using SO. Can you please benefit to SO community by explaining how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue and solution is noted in Redhat's link here:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5692661

In summary, it's not normal to run commands as sudo in a userdata script, thus the default policy is to not allow this, which causes a 25sec delay while it attempts to run pam_systemd and times out due to the dbus 25sec timeout.

In my case I was attempting to run `su <user> -c "command"`. My error was found by running `journalctl -b` (-b is for current boot session). And you can find the related error log like:

```
pam_systemd(su:session): Failed to create session: Connection time out
```